# Python PonyORM One to one mapping

Tags: python-3.x, ponyorm

I am trying to create a one-to-one mapping using Pony ORM.

```
class ApplierIngress(ApplierObjectMapper.db.Entity):
    correlation_id = orm.PrimaryKey(str)
    ticket_number  = orm.Required(str)
    username       = orm.Required(str)
    status         = orm.Required(str)
    request_date   = orm.Required(datetime)

class ApplierResult(ApplierObjectMapper.db.Entity):
    correlation_id = orm.Required(ApplierIngress)
    result         = orm.Required(orm.LongStr)
    request_date   = orm.Required(datetime)
```

It throws error while generating the mapping

`pony.orm.core.ERDiagramError: Reverse attribute for ApplierResult.correlation_id not found`

I want correlation_id in ApplierResult table be the foreign key referencing to correlation_id in ApplierIngress table

Please let me know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As error said you need to specify reverse attribute. Entities is not just Tables.

```
class ApplierIngress(ApplierObjectMapper.db.Entity):
    correlation_id = orm.PrimaryKey(str)
    ticket_number  = orm.Required(str)
    username       = orm.Required(str)
    status         = orm.Required(str)
    request_date   = orm.Required(datetime)
    result_id      = orm.Optional('ApplierResult') # this attribute should be added       

class ApplierResult(ApplierObjectMapper.db.Entity):
    correlation_id = orm.Required(ApplierIngress)
    result         = orm.Required(orm.LongStr)
    request_date   = orm.Required(datetime)
```

Since this class is not yet declared you should use it as string or lambda

`result_id = orm.Optional('ApplierResult')`

`result_id = orm.Optional(lambda: ApplierResult)`

See [here](https://docs.ponyorm.org/relationships.html)

Comment: What if I do not need the reverse? For example: if I have a table that will only be consulted through its elements IDs/primary keys?

Comment: @meyer1994 do you understand the difference between tables and entities?
If you want to work with entities as tables for some reason - just use `result_id = orm.Optional(int)`. But it is not behavior we expect.